# Why does chrome not accept the letters 'c' or 'h'

Tags: google-chrome

Using Windows and the latest Chrome version.

The letters work in notepad and in other browsers and application.

In Chrome the letters don't work either in input boxes or even on the URL line to type an address.

I have to copy and paste from notepad to have these characters.

This is as weird as it sounds.  I haven't found any plugins or extensions that would cause this.

Comment: What chrome version do you have? I have never encountered this problem before

Comment: This happes to me occasionally. The buttons just aren't accepted. I have to restart the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> I found that if I hit the Windows key (between the left Ctrl and Alt keys) then the problem would correct and the c, v, h keys started working again.

Taken from: [Google Forums - Google Chrome Keys Problem](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/chrome/C%2420V%2420H/chrome/GBuxA5fbFMQ/pcX7WRWy5XwJ)

Comment: Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Did a Google search and found multiple forums pointing to this same problem with this solution. Sounds like a `Win` key stuck scenario. You could also try disabling extensions, just to be sure.